# Diagonal li element / automatic increment for next child

Tags: html, css, list, sass, increment

I am trying to acheive something like this :

> Element 1
>
> ```
>     Element 2
>
>            Element 3
> ```

For now, I got it woking, with those code :

HTML :

```
<ul>
<li>Element 1</li>
<li>Element 2</li>
<li>Element 3</li>
....
<li>Element 12</li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
ul{
  :nth-child(2) {padding-left: 1em;}
  :nth-child(3) {padding-left: 2em;}
   ....
  :nth-child(12) {padding-left: 13em;}
  }
```

But I am wondering if there is a simpler solution or more correct one to automatize this as I have 10+ elements in my list. I would prefer a css solution as all my content is generated via php and I want it responsive.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally found a "CSS" solution, SCSS one.

```
ul{
    margin-top: 0;
    @for $i from 2 through 12 {
    $j: 1em;
    :nth-child(#{$i}) {padding-left: $j*$i;}
    }
}
```

And it makes the increment responsive as I can include mediaqueries around it.

Comment: mr Dikeneko SASS is also javascript program. and i think it javascript used by even everyone but at least new learner don't use sess as much as javascript..

Comment: I never said I searched for a "new learner" solution. It is CSS in the sense that it ends up in the CSS file. Also, I'm a girl, and don't downvote my answer just because you're upset I didn't upvoted yours? Seriously?

Comment: no there is no such a reason. just because sess is preprocessor not actual css. and one more thing i wanna mention you this type of question should never ask any experienced one it's understood he is beginner. any ways what about PHP or .net?? is it html?? no this is HTML generator programming. and sess is not css but css generator programming. think. miss dikeneko.

Answer (score -1):

try this [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/nhchwgLr/)

```
<ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
    <li>Element 12</li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
var count = 20;
$('ul').find('li').each(function(){
    count += 20;
    $(this).css('padding-left','+='+count+'px');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I said I'm looking more for a CSS solution, not a jquery one.

Comment: i think it's not possible but i'm not sure... any ways if this answer is useful for you please vote this answer

Comment: For CSS questions, providing a JS solution is frowned on unless it is simply not possible to do it with pure CSS.